# Change element depending on Hover on pseudo element

Tags: html, css, frontend, pseudo-element

I need to change an element depending on the hover state of a pseudo element. Here is what I got but it does not work:

```
nav .logo {
  display: none;
}
nav:before{}
nav:hover:before .logo {
  display: block;
}
```

The div should display if I hover over the before "element". Thank you for any help!

Comment: For this kind of question you really need to post your HTML; because there can be no elements contained within a generated, pseudo-, element.

Comment: Note that `nav:hover:before` will match the pseudo-element in response to the `nav` being hovered. If you want the pseudo-element to be the target of `:hover`, you'd better use an actual HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You are trying to select an element with class `.logo` that is a **descendant** of the the `nav` element's `:before` pseudo element.

It's not working because `.logo` isn't a descendant. Furthermore, pseudo elements can't contain children elements.

---

You can, however, select *sibling* elements of the pseudo element. This wouldn't work unless you changed your markup, though.

For instance:

```
nav:hover:before + .logo {
  display: block;
}
```

..but that's clearly not what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Any advice what would be the best solution for my problem?

Comment: @jonicious Well what does your HTML look like? Do you mind providing an [example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help!

I wanted to go with a pseudo element but unfortunately it is better to go with a "real" HTML element. My markup looks like this:

```
<nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="menu-header-menue-container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menue" class="menu">
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And my (S)CSS:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/30x30);

  ul {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    ul {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```